# Cross compile Linux kernel module with correct library search path

Tags: linux-kernel, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to build an arm64 module on an x86 host.

1. I have the target rootfs mounted as /mnt/rpi_rootfs
2. I installed the kernel header files in the rootfs (/mnt/rpi_rootfs/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.32-v8+).

   2.1. Note that the actual used target kernel is 5.10.92-v8+, but the headers package was not available for that version. This has to be fixed later.
3. I built a cross compiler: /home/dinne/x-tools/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu-gcc

The module is built using:

make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu-

which calls

make -C /mnt/rpi_rootfs/lib/modules/5.15.32-v8+/build M=$(PWD) modules

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/rpi_rootfs/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.32-v8+'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110
  You are using:           aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu-gcc (crosstool-NG 1.25.0_rc1) 10.3.0
/home/dinne/cm4/dma_ip_drivers/XDMA/linux-kernel/xdma/Makefile:17: XVC_FLAGS: .
  CC [M]  /home/dinne/cm4/dma_ip_drivers/XDMA/linux-kernel/xdma/libxdma.o
/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1: No such file or directory
```

Of course it is correct that /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 cannot be found, as it should use the target rootfs. It is there in the target rootfs: mnt/rpi_rootfs/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1

```
ls /mnt/rpi_rootfs/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 -al 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 dec 1 11:52 /mnt/rpi_rootfs/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 -> aarch64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
```

So the file is in: /mnt/rpi_rootfs/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so

How can I make sure it uses that location?

Update:

I tried this:

```
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=/home/dinne/x-tools/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu- LD=home/dinne/x-tools/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu-ld SHELL='sh -x'
```

Result:

```
  CC [M]  /home/dinne/cm4/dma_ip_drivers/XDMA/linux-kernel/xdma/libxdma.o
+ /home/dinne/x-tools/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu-gcc -Wp,-MMD,/home/dinne/cm4/dma_ip_drivers/XDMA/linux-kernel/xdma/.libxdma.o.d -nostdinc -isystem /home/dinne/x-tools/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu/10.3.0/include -I./arch/arm64/include -I./arch/arm64/include/generated -I./include -I./arch/arm64/include/uapi -I./arch/arm64/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -mlittle-endian -DCC_USING_PATCHABLE_FUNCTION_ENTRY -DKASAN_SHADOW_SCALE_SHIFT= -fmacro-prefix-map=./= -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mgeneral-regs-only -DCONFIG_CC_HAS_K_CONSTRAINT=1 -Wno-psabi -mabi=lp64 -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-unwind-tables -mbranch-protection=pac-ret+leaf+bti -Wa,-march=armv8.5-a -DARM64_ASM_ARCH="armv8.5-a" -DKASAN_SHADOW_SCALE_SHIFT= -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -Wno-address-of-packed-member -O2 -fno-allow-store-data-races -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wno-main -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-stack-clash-protection -fpatchable-function-entry=2 -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-stringop-truncation -Wno-zero-length-bounds -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-restrict -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -Wno-packed-not-aligned -mstack-protector-guard=sysreg -mstack-protector-guard-reg=sp_el0 -mstack-protector-guard-offset=1344 -I/home/dinne/cm4/dma_ip_drivers/XDMA/linux-kernel/include -DMODULE -DKBUILD_BASENAME="libxdma" -DKBUILD_MODNAME="xdma" -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_xdma -c -o /home/dinne/cm4/dma_ip_drivers/XDMA/linux-kernel/xdma/libxdma.o /home/dinne/cm4/dma_ip_drivers/XDMA/linux-kernel/xdma/libxdma.c
+ scripts/basic/fixdep /home/dinne/cm4/dma_ip_drivers/XDMA/linux-kernel/xdma/.libxdma.o.d /home/dinne/cm4/dma_ip_drivers/XDMA/linux-kernel/xdma/libxdma.o /home/dinne/x-tools/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu-gcc -Wp,-MMD,/home/dinne/cm4/dma_ip_drivers/XDMA/linux-kernel/xdma/.libxdma.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /home/dinne/x-tools/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu/10.3.0/include -I./arch/arm64/include -I./arch/arm64/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/arm64/include/uapi -I./arch/arm64/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -mlittle-endian -DCC_USING_PATCHABLE_FUNCTION_ENTRY -DKASAN_SHADOW_SCALE_SHIFT= -fmacro-prefix-map=./= -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mgeneral-regs-only -DCONFIG_CC_HAS_K_CONSTRAINT=1 -Wno-psabi -mabi=lp64 -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-unwind-tables -mbranch-protection=pac-ret+leaf+bti -Wa,-march=armv8.5-a -DARM64_ASM_ARCH='"armv8.5-a"' -DKASAN_SHADOW_SCALE_SHIFT= -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -Wno-address-of-packed-member -O2 -fno-allow-store-data-races -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wno-main -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-stack-clash-protection -fpatchable-function-entry=2 -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-stringop-truncation -Wno-zero-length-bounds -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-restrict -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -Wno-packed-not-aligned -mstack-protector-guard=sysreg -mstack-protector-guard-reg=sp_el0 -mstack-protector-guard-offset=1344 -I/home/dinne/cm4/dma_ip_drivers/XDMA/linux-kernel/include  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"libxdma"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"xdma"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_xdma -c -o /home/dinne/cm4/dma_ip_drivers/XDMA/linux-kernel/xdma/libxdma.o /home/dinne/cm4/dma_ip_drivers/XDMA/linux-kernel/xdma/libxdma.c
/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1: No such file or directory
```

If I temporarily copy ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 to /lib then the error goes away, but next a missing libc.so.6 is reported.

Comment: *"Note that the actual used target kernel is 5.10.92-v8+, but the headers package was not available for that version"* - well even if you succeed at compiling that's not goin to work. Can't compile with mismatching kernel headers and target kernel. Get rid of the 5.15.32 headers and compile the kernel and the headers yourself or find the right package. As per the `ld` not being found I think it's because your `aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu-ld` is a symlink to `/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1`, so either change that or try with `LD=...`.

Comment: Ok. I'll look into getting the correct headers.

About the linking issue:

ls /mnt/rpi_rootfs/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 -al
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 dec  1 11:52 /mnt/rpi_rootfs/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 -> aarch64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so

So the file is in: /mnt/rpi_rootfs/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so

The cross linker is in /home/dinne/x-tools/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu-ld


How do I use LD=... to solve the linking issue?

Comment: You can try with `make ...other stuff... LD=/home/dinne/x-tools/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu-ld`

Comment: Same error using your suggestion. See updated question.